# How can I determine the complexity of this small program?

Tags: java

```java
package maguen_3;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Maguen_3_test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        randomPLaylist(10);

    }
    public static void randomPLaylist(int num) {
        int[] songsArray = new int[num];
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            songsArray[i] = (int)(Math.random()*num) + 1;
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if(songsArray[i] == songsArray[j]){
                    i--;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(songsArray));
    }

}
```

This is a small program that shuffles a playlist.
The function randomPlaylist receives the length of the playlist.
I know intuitively that it is O(n * log n), but I don't know how to explain it with words.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please clarify your question: what behaviour do you expect, what error do you get, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It's not `O(n*log n)`.

You should count the number of iterations of both loops.

The outer loop has `num` iterations. Let's denote `num` with `n`.

The inner loop has `i` iterations in the worst case (if the condition is never `true`).

The first time the inner loop runs it has 0 iterations.

The second time it runs, it has 1 iteration.

The last time it runs, it has `n - 1` iterations.

Therefore the total time is `1` + `2` + ... + `n - 1` = `n * (n - 1) / 2` = `O(n^2)`